# Set Javascript Instance Variables programmatically 

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, instance-variables

I'm going to be getting an array of objects and want to set instance variables inside of a class based on a property. So if I get this:

```
ary = [{type: 'walrus', name: 'GorbyPuff'}, {type: 'humanoid', occupation: 'KingSlayer'}]
```

I want to initialize an object where `@walrus == ary[0]` and `@humanoid == ary[1]`

In Ruby I could user instance_variable_set, but how can this be accomplished in the Javascripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get what you're trying to acchieve, but the easiest way to do this would be:

```
var theObj = {};
for(var i=0;i<ary.length;i++)
{
    theObj[ary[i].type] = ary[i];
}
```

The worry here is, that by altering the `ary` variable you will inadvertently alter the `theObj`:

```
console.log(theObj.walrus.name);//Outputs: GorbyPuff
ary[0].name = 'Nips!';
console.log(theObj.walrus.name);//Outputs: Nips! <-- objects are passed by reference, always
```

If the `ary` variable is part of a function scope, and the resulting object is its return value, you needn't worry. But if both are part of the global scope (Which they shouldn't, it's bad practice), this becomes an issue.

I therefore propose this approach:

```
var obj = {};
var i;
while (ary.length !== 0)
{
    i = ary.splice(0,1)[0];//removes element from array
    if (i.hasOwnProperty('type'))//always best to check the property you're going to use is there
    {
        obj[i.type] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript passes all objects by reference, so any change made to the objects in ary will also be made to any references to it.

Comment: boomsauce, perfect. I was doing it inside of a constructor so it turned out to be `this[obj['type']] = obj` As long as you're pretty sure they are unique, you're good

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in JS that can do this for you, just do a loop to build the object you want:

```
ary = [{type: 'walrus', name: 'GorbyPuff'}, {type: 'humanoid', occupation: 'KingSlayer'}]
instances={}
for(x=0;x<ary.length;x++) instances[ary[x].type]=ary[x]

document.write(instances.walrus.name) //GorbyBuff
document.write(instances.humanoid.occupation) //KingSlayer
```

Comment: I am instantializing an instance of a class, so the instances will all be of the same type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that array of objects as prototypes, you can do this:

```
var Walrus = function(){};
Walrus.prototype=ary[0];
var aWalrus = new Walrus(); // creates a new Walrus.  aWalrus.name => GorbyPuff
```

In Javascript the Good Parts, Douglas Crawford describes a more general way of doing it:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
   Object.create = function (o) {
      var F = function () {};
      F.prototype = o;
      return new F();
   };
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
var aWalrus = Object.create(ary[0]);
```

Comment: Well, like you said in your answer, the question was unclear.  I interpreted it differently.  Maybe he just wanted var x = ary[0]... I don't know.  It seems like he might not understand javascript objects very well, so this answer could well help him even if it's off-topic.

Comment: Also, he said "set instance variables inside of a class based on a property", and I interpreted class to mean something like prototype.

Answer (score 0):

here is a example of what you want:

```
// the class:
function MyClass(){
  // stuff
}

// the data object
var o = [
  {type:"MyClass",name:"a name"}
]

// how to instantiate:
var instances = [];
for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){
  if(typeof this[o[i].type] == "function")
    instances.push(new this[o[i].type](o[i].name))
}
```

If you create the classes in a function you need to use "this" as a reference to that function, else you can use "window"